# Set loading with React useEffect fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to show a loading spinner while fetching data from an api, and show error or results once finished using useEffect. For some reason `isLoading` is set to false before fetching is finished.

Could you please help me what could be the problem?

```
const ProblemTable: React.FC<IProblemTableProps> = (props) => {
    // List of problems to show on the table
    const [problems, setProblems] = useState<IProblem[]>([]);

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();

    useEffect(() => {
            TierService.getProblems(props.tier, setProblems, setError);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
    }, [problems, error]);

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Loading message="Loading problems..." />;
    }

    if (error) {
        return <ErrorMessage title="Failed fetching problems" />;
    }

        return <>...</>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useEffect` that sets loading to `false` is called when the component mounts. Add a condition that would only turn loading to `false` when the api call ended.

For example - if there are any problems or there's an error set loading to `false`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(problems.length || error) setIsLoading(false);
}, [problems, error]);
```

However, if there are no problems or an error, `loading` would stay `true`, so you'll probably need a more strict condition. A better way would be to set loading to `false` if any of the callbacks are called:

```
useEffect(() => {
  TierService.getProblems(
    props.tier,
    p => {
      setProblems(p);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    e => { 
      setError(e);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  );
}, []);
```

Depending on the implementation of `TierService.getProblems` the 2nd suggestion would fail if no callback is called when the response is empty.

I would probably create a Promise based API which would allow you to use `async/await` with `try/catch/finally`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const api = async () => {
    try {
      const problems = await TierService.getProblems(props.tier);
      setProblems(problems);
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  api();
}, []);
```

Comment: Empty array result was my problem also with your first option. However the problem is solved with setting isLoading to false on declaration, then set to true after calling service. And then I can clear on the useEffect called on changes in problem and/or error. I was not awere of that this useEffect is called also when component mounted.